# autocomplete input on mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, mapbox

I've recently discover mapbox.js (http://mapbox.com/) which i'd like to implement on my website. implementation is quite simple, but i'm getting stuck at few things: 1. I'd like an input with autocomplete with matching location & make the map going to that location.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an update on this since @tmcw responded.

The autocomplete feature was [added as of v2.1.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/issues/264#issuecomment-56456781) (current stable is v2.1.4).

You can check out an example of how to use it [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geocoding-auto/).

Comment: is there a way to style that?

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete isn't yet implemented in MapBox.js: [this is the ticket for implementing it](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/issues/264).